# React issue with rendering data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Basically I have an issue with rendering information got from firebase to the screen.
When I'm trying to call the function which gets the information from the database inside componentDidMount(), the function is not even executed, but when I call it inside the render() function, which I know it's now the right thing to do it works, it goes into an infinite loop and it keeps accessing the database over and over again, but it renders the correct information to the screen. So the function itself is not the issue, I guess, since it is able to retrieve the information from the database.
Also a console.log() inside the componentDidMount() seems to work so componentDidMount() does fire.
 So how should I go forward with this issue? I've been struggling with this for several hours now. I can't seem to find the issue.

This is my code:

```
export default class Cars extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            cars: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadCarsFromDB();
    }

    loadCarsFromDB = () => (
        <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
            {firebase => {
                firebase.accessFirebase("cars").get()
                    .then(snapshot => {
                        let cars = [];
                        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                          cars.push(doc.data());
                        })
                        return cars;
                    })
                    .then(cars => {
                        this.setState({cars: cars});
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
            }
        </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    )

    renderCars = () => {
        return this.state.cars.map(car => <Car
            brandName={car.brandName}
            model={car.model}
            color={car.color}
            price={car.price} />)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="car-item">
                {this.renderCars()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Firebase class except the credentials

```
export default class Firebase {
    constructor() {
        app.initializeApp(config);
    }

    accessFirebase = () => {
        let db = app.firestore();
        return db.collection("cars");
    }
}
```

This is the Car function

```
const car = (props) => (
    <div className="Car">
        <span>{props.brandName ? props.brandName : "Nu exista"}</span>
        <span>{props.model ? props.model : "Nu exista"}</span>
        <span>{props.color ? props.color : "Nu exista"}</span>
        <span>{props.price ? props.price : "Nu exista"}</span>
    </div>
)

export default car;
```

And this is the index.js file. I don't know, maybe it has something to do with the use of contexts. I basically create only one firebase instance which should allow me to query the database from anywhere in the code by using only this very instance.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
        <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.jsx file

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Cars/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to use the FirebaseContext.Consumer component from loadCarsFromDB. So I would lift up FirebaseContext.Consumer around Cars and pass down the firebase property as a prop.

```js
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
            {firebase => (
              <Cars firebase={firebase}/>
              )
            }
          <FirebaseContext.Consumer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
    loadCarsFromDB = () => (
      this.props.firebase.accessFirebase("cars").get()
          .then(snapshot => {
              let cars = [];
              snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                cars.push(doc.data());
              })
              return cars;
          })
          .then(cars => {
              this.setState({cars: cars});
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
          });
    )
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it seems to be working. But why this works and the way I did it does not?

Comment: When you called loadCarsFromDB from render, then the Context component provided the firebase reference. But you should not call it from the renderer, and the state update causes rerendering and infinite loop.